# Samsung Gear VR - Publish Gear VR Application

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, gear-vr

What I need to publish my first game on Gear VR store

I read this documentation but I was wondering if there more information

http://static.oculus.com/sdk-downloads/documents/OculusMobile_SubmissionGuidelines.pdf

**Oculus Signature File (required during development, remove for submission)**

**Android Application Signature (required for submission)**

My Questions ?

1- when I create APK , I should create signed APK only .

2- How long they take to publish my application .

3- Is there other stores or just that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some more information on the [Oculus Developer site](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/publish/latest/):

It covers some general stuff, like comfort requirements.

e.g.

> Verify that all of your app’s UI elements are rendered stereoscopically and are clear and legible.
>
> Make sure your app avoids using a shaky camera and avoids acceleration not directed by the user.
>
> Make sure your app maintains or exceeds the minimum 60fps frame rate.
>
> Make sure your app does not lock the camera to the user's head.

With regard to your specific questions:

1. This is covered in the documentation you linked:

> All developers must create their own unique digital signature and sign their applications before submitting them
> to Oculus for approval. For more information and instructions, please see Android's "Signing your Applications"
> documentation: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html
> Make sure to save the certificate file you use to sign your application. Every subsequent update to your
> application must be signed with the same certificate file, or it will fail.
> Note: Your application must be signed by an Android certificate before you submit it.

2. Not sure but if it's anything like Apple's process it could vary between as little as an hour to as much as a fortnight.
3. You can probably publish to the Android play store *as a Google Cardboard app* and let users use it by flipping the Gear-VR USB connecter out of the way.
   This is how I use it for Google Cardboard apps.

Comment: I need to build apk file without submission ? can I do that

Comment: #3 won't work, the gear-vr api will require a certificate for each device (ties to an unique device id) and will not work without it.

Answer (score 2):

About the question 3, it seemed that there is no other markets/stores for gear vr. But inface you can publish your app to google play or amazon store.

And notice the user that this is for gear vr. Maybe add a small vr picture on your icon is better for users to get it.